# Angular 6 loading child route component when parent requested

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two sections of my app, a family profile and a member profile. I have my routes set up like so: (simplified)

app.routes.ts:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'family/:familyId',
      loadChildren: './core/containers/family/family.module#FamilyModule'
    }
];
```

family.routes.ts:

```
export const familyRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'profile',
        component: FamilyProfileComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'member/:memberId',
        loadChildren: '../member/member.module#MemberModule'
    },
];
```

member.routes.ts

```
export const memberRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'profile',
        component: MemberProfileComponent
    },
];
```

When I request either

/family/fam_1/profile

or

/family/fam_1/member/mbr_1/profile

Both routes display the MemberProfileComponent and I cannot get the FamilyProfileComponent to show.

Comment: Can you post your app routes?

Comment: there is no route with the path `/family`?

Comment: Updated with app routes

Comment: Post your all `html` also. We need to check how many `<router-outlet>` you have used.

Comment: Just one <router-outlet>

Comment: You need more than one `<router-outlet>` as per your condition. Other wise how it will work. Give me some time i will create stackblitz for that

Comment: It's very odd that both routes would display the `MemberProfileComponent` when that's the most specific route.

Comment: Yes, when I comment out the MemberProfileComponent route, it routes correctly to the FamilyProfileComponent

Comment: Hope my stackblitz help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my FamilyModule was importing my MemberModule when it should not have been.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbaucv

This is a working example and both profiles work.

Family Profile: https://angular-hbaucv.stackblitz.io/family/fam_1/profile

Member Profile: https://angular-hbaucv.stackblitz.io/family/fam_1/member/mbr_1/profile

app-routing.module.ts

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'family/:familyId', loadChildren: './family/family.module#FamilyModule' }
]
```

family-routing.module.ts

```
export const familyRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile', component: FamilyProfileComponent },
  { path: 'member/:memberId', loadChildren: './member/member.module#MemberModule' }
]
```

member-routing.module.ts

```
export const memberRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile', component: MemberProfileComponent },
]
```

Comment: Hmm it appears that I have everything setup the same, I am using ngrx with the @ngrx/router-store. I'm wondering if maybe the issue is in that.

Comment: I just added all the @ngrx/router-store code to your example and it's still working. I'll have to keep digging, it's probably something stupid.

Comment: Haha, it usually is.

Comment: Yep. Turns out my FamilyModule was importing my MemberModule when it should not have been. Found that out by commenting the loadchildren route out and it was still routing me to it. I'll upvote your answers though because it was helpful in figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

First do change into your family module file.

Like this :

```
const familyRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'profile' },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: FamilyprofileComponent,
    children: [     
      {
        path: 'member/:memberId',
        loadChildren: './familyprofile/member/member.module#MemberModule'
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

instead of

```
const familyRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'profile',
        component: FamilyProfileComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'member/:memberId',
        loadChildren: '../member/member.module#MemberModule'
    },
];
```

Than Add `<router-outlet>` into your `FamilyProfileComponent` template(html).
Like This :

**FamilyProfileComponent.html**

```
// Your parent html code
<router-outlet></router-outlet> // Child html content will display here.
```

## Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsagmd)